# How to add a Reminder for an Activity via Rest API in Bitrix24 CRM?

Tags: bitrix

I'm working on a NodeJS integration to manage Leads. I'm currently able to create Leads and an Activity connected to the Lead using the endpoint `/crm.activity.todo.add.json`.

Now I need to notify the Responsible of the Activity to attend that activity, so I'm trying to create a reminder for that activity.

I can't find any way to achieve it in the Bitrix Docs. However, I notice that the Activity has a field `NOTIFY_TYPE` and `NOTIFY_VALUE`
https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/rest_activity/crm_activity_fields.php

I've also analyzed the web app to see if I could intercept the URLs it uses under the hood and I noticed that it uses this PHP page:

https://avify.bitrix24.es/bitrix/services/main/ajax.php?action=crm.activity.todo.updatePingOffsets

and sends this form data:

```
Action: crm.activity.todo.updatePingOffsets

Form data:
- ownerTypeId: 1 // lead type
- ownerId: 555 // lead id
- id: 1111 // task id
- value[0]: 30 // minutes
```

and it returned me a 400 error.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to create a reminder for an activity via Rest API:

```
const addReminderToActivity = async (
    activityId: number,
    itemId: number,
    itemType: ItemType
  ) => {
    const ownerTypeIds = {
      'LEAD': 1,
      'CONTACT': 3,
      'COMPANY': 4
    };

    const minutesBeforeDeadline = 15;

    return axios.post('/crm.activity.todo.updatePingOffsets.json', {
      ownerTypeId: ownerTypeIds[itemType],
      ownerId: itemId,
      id: activityId,
      value: [minutesBeforeDeadline]
    });
  };
```

As [@usersuper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78055076/7287324) says, there is not an API method in the docs, but I found this endpoint by analyzing the web app requests, so it seems the method exists but it's not documented.

This is a GitHub gist I made as reference:
https://gist.github.com/ChemaCLi/9c3b18e8bf59026561f65338d72decc7

It allows to:

- registerLead
- getLeadResponsible
- addReminderToActivity
- getContactResponsible
- createActivityForCRMItem
- findLeadOrContactByPhoneOrEmail

Answer (score 0):

There is no REST API method to add reminders for the activity type 'TODO' now. You only can use deadline field to visual control.
NOTIFY_TYPE and NOTIFY_VALUE rest fields not implemented now for "TODO"